# k8s with kubespray fails at dns config

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My k8s with kubespray always bails out at the following error
`"Too many nameservers. You can relax this check by set docker_dns_servers_strict=no and we will only use the first 3`

In my cluster.yml I have this under `- hosts`
`- docker_dns_servers_strict: no` but I still get the error.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked with adding  `-e 'docker_dns_servers_strict=no'`:

```
ansible-playbook -i ../inventories/kubernetes.yaml --become --become-user=root cluster.yml -e 'docker_dns_servers_strict=no'
```

Answer (score 0):

As [explained here](https://www.wanglibing.com/kubernetes/book/%E5%B8%B8%E8%A7%81%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98/Too%20many%20nameservers.html), check the format of your yaml file.

Here is one example:

```
- hosts: k8s-cluster:etcd:calico-rr
  any_errors_fatal: "{{ any_errors_fatal | default(true) }}"
  vars:
    - docker_dns_servers_strict: no
  roles:
    - { role: kubespray-defaults}
    - { role: kernel-upgrade, tags: kernel-upgrade, when: kernel_upgrade is defined and kernel_upgrade }
    - { role: kubernetes/preinstall, tags: preinstall }
    - { role: docker, tags: docker }
    - role: rkt
      tags: rkt
      when: "'rkt' in [etcd_deployment_type, kubelet_deployment_type, vault_deployment_type]"
```

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/issues/2449#issuecomment-372935582):

> This usually happens if you configure one set of dns servers on the servers **before you run the kubespray role**.

Comment: I have VMs that may already have the dns configured you mean? Could you tell me how to get around it? I have already changed the flag and I had gone through that link before posting here but I get the error still

Comment: @curiousengineer I don't have much more information, except that this error can occur when the kubespray role is set too late.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added `docker_dns_servers_strict: false` in the **all.yaml** file. It's solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

below worked for my installation by trimming the nameserver to max 6

added it in **roles/container-engine/docker/tasks/set_facts_dns.yml**
just below trim the nameserver

```
- name: rtrim number of numbers of search domain to 6
  set_fact:
    docker_dns_search_domains: "{{ docker_dns_search_domains[0:6] }}"
  when: docker_dns_search_domains|length > 6
```